# Is this line from Rockstar referring to Paradise?

Tags: dialogue, rockstar-2011

I watched the Indian movie *Rockstar* (2011) directed by Imtiaz Ali. In the movie Jordan says

> You know, there is a place far away from here, beyond the concept of wrongdoing and rightdoing. I will meet you there

It has a lot of influence on me. I found it is a line from a poem written by poet Rumi. The question is whether this specific line is about "paradise" (where there is no concept of wrongdoing or right doing?

Answer (score 1):

Its a poem by Rumi as you've said

```
Beyond our ideas of right-doing and wrong-doing,
there is a field. I’ll meet you there.
When the soul lies down in that grass,
the world is too full to talk about.
Ideas, language, even the phrase ‘each other’ doesn’t make sense any more.

Rumi
```

I dont know if this is the appropriate place to ask about poetry, but nevertheless here goes. To different people this may be paradise, this may be afterlife, this may be referring to freedom, salvation or even death.

So it can be interpreted in many ways. I prefer Paradise and Salvation. 
IF you consider the movie, he most definitely means salvation and afterlife (which is paradise to him to meet the heroine as shes dead)